# Modified the description for single instance/exception in recurrence appointment does not reflecting in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

**Hi,
We have our custom "Store Provider" written for Outlook.

Problem occur when we have modified the single instance in recurrence appointment in Outlook it does not reflecting in calendar view.
This is working fine with Outlook 2010 and 2013 but does not works Outlook 2016 onwards.
Does not knowing which property need to be set for the Outlook 2016?
For Outlook 2010 we are setting below properties which is working as expected:
Observed that commenting the PR_HTML property for meeting works with the Outlook 2016 as it shows description from PR_BODY_W property. Does this means that i am setting wrongly PR_HTML property.**

```
props[index].dwAlignPad = 0;
props[index].ulPropTag = PR_BODY_W;
props[index++].Value.lpszW = pwszTemp;

props[index].dwAlignPad = 0;
props[index].ulPropTag = PR_INTERNET_CPID;
props[index++].Value.l = lCodePage;

***props[index].dwAlignPad = 0;
props[index].ulPropTag = PR_HTML;
props[index].Value.bin.lpb = (LPBYTE)spAnsiiHTML.get();
props[index++].Value.bin.cb = (ULONG)strlen(spAnsiiHTML.get());
```

---

**Modifying the single instance in recurring appointment creating an exception. But we are not setting any code in exception stream does we need to set there? Below is the code how we are creating the exception stream:**

```
hResult = lpMessage->OpenProperty(m_ApptOrTask.GetRecurringStreamTag(), &IID_IStream, STGM_READWRITE, MAPI_MODIFY, (LPUNKNOWN *)pRecurrenceStream.getptr());
if (FAILED(hResult) && (MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND == hResult))
{
    // we need to try to create this stream
    hResult = lpMessage->OpenProperty(m_ApptOrTask.GetRecurringStreamTag(), &IID_IStream, STGM_READWRITE, MAPI_CREATE | MAPI_MODIFY, (LPUNKNOWN *)pRecurrenceStream.getptr());
    if (FAILED(hResult))
    {
        LOG_ERROR(_T("Cannot open reccurrence pattern stream"));
        return hResult;
    }
}

 // m_wRecurFrequency
hResult = pStream->Write(&m_wRecurFrequency, sizeof (WORD), &cbWritten);
if (FAILED(hResult) || (cbWritten != sizeof (WORD)))
{
    LOG_ERROR(_T("Failed to write recurrence stream: m_wRecurFrequency"));
    return MAPI_E_CALL_FAILED;
}

// m_wPatternType
hResult = pStream->Write(&m_wPatternType, sizeof (WORD), &cbWritten);
if (FAILED(hResult) || (cbWritten != sizeof (WORD)))
{
    LOG_ERROR(_T("Failed to write recurrence stream: m_wPatternType"));
    return hResult;
}
```

**Any pointers or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: Have you tried to compare the recurrence blob and the embedded exception message in Outlook Spy (click IMessage button) for the good (created by Outlook) and bad (created by your code) appointments?

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes I have compared them and found that PidLidFExceptionalBody  is missing from my code; Now after setting it works fine with HTML data. But now seeing another problem when I have creating an exception from my code its getting lock for modification. Becomes read-only and i cant edit the description in it. Any pointer on this?

Comment: In addition to Exception body cant change the exception "Location" and "Time" as well .. All becomes read-only :(